# How to get horizontal lines using hough transform

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am currently referring to geeks for geeks code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
  
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
  
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180, 200)
  
for r,theta in lines[0]:
      
    a = np.cos(theta)
  
    b = np.sin(theta)
      
    x0 = a*r
      
    y0 = b*r
      
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
      
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
  
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
      
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
      
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,255),2)
      
cv2.imwrite('linesDetected.jpg', img)
```

I want to get the horizontal lines of the railway track sleepers, like this paper: https://www.ijcseonline.org/pub_paper/26-IJCSE-01514.pdf

Comment: What is your question? Looks like you found a piece of code and a paper in pdf, what else have you tried and what is your result?

Comment: Hello, I only want to extract the railway tracks in the form of lines from the image.

Comment: Is there a sample/testcase/image/...  ? :)

Comment: @Shamshirsaz.Navid Please check the paper i have linked

Comment: You can use "adaptiveThreshold" to create a mask. Then clear the image noise and use "findContours" to find large Blobs.